# c++11 accessing "this" from lambda passed to constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Is there an elegant way of accessing "this" in a lambda that is passed to the constructor?

This works, but is not elegant!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class CbClass {
 public:
  CbClass(int x, std::function< void() > cb) : x_(x),cb_(cb) {}
  int x_;
  std::function< void() > cb_;
  void call() { if (cb_) cb_(); };
};

int main() {

  CbClass* p(nullptr);
  CbClass** pp(&p);
  CbClass cb( 13 , [pp] () { std::cout << (*pp)->x_ << std::endl; } );
  p = &cb;

  cb.call();

}
```

Comment: If it works, then its not appropriate for this site, a better place would be [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You would pass `this` to the lambda in the `call` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class CbClass {
public:
    CbClass(int x, std::function< void( CbClass * ) > cb) : x_(x),cb_(cb) {}
    int x_;
    std::function< void( CbClass * ) > cb_;
    void call() { if (cb_) cb_( this ); };
};

int main() {
   CbClass cb( 13 , [] ( CbClass *p ) { std::cout << p->x_ << std::endl; } );
   cb.call();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access `this`. You can access a random captured `CbClass` object, which the caller arranges to be the object under construction. You don't need to manipulate any pointers for that.

```
int main() {
  CbClass cb(13, [&cb]() { std::cout << cb.x_ << std::endl; });
  cb.call();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is better, but gives a warning with g++ 4.8: warning: variable 'cb' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]. Any way round that without turning the warning off?

Comment: Keep in mind that this will end terribly if say, you return `cb` from this function.